# printing text in qt mainwindow.ui window in my widget application

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I know that Label is what i use to set some text in a single line, however I want to print multiple lines, more specifically is a loop foreach that will print all the data the user entered previously. There is some way?

Answer (score 1):

Create object of `QTextEdit`. Set `QTextEdit::setReadOnly(true);` If you need only to show data of user in window.

You can past your text in cycle via **html:** `QTextEdit::setHtml(const QString &text)`.

Or if it simple text then use **slot:** `QTextEdit::insertPlainText(const QString &text)`

More:

```
QTextEdit::setText(const QString &text)
QTextEdit::setPlainText(const QString &text)
```

Look here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is a way to do that...

make sure you set the "wordWrap" attribute in the label to true...
[image]

and new lines are scaped using **\n**

```
ui->myLabel->setText("asdasda\n...Asdasdasdasdasd\n...--Docker\nno\Mac");
```